# Index out of range (PHAsset)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, phasset

I'm trying to convert `PSAssets` into `UIImage` and it was working up until 3 hours and then something happened (no clue what I did) and now all I'm getting as error is:

> Thread 17: Fatal error: Index out of range

It just drives me crazy for hours and I cant figure it out.

```
func convertAssetToImages() -> Void {

    if !selectedAssets.isEmpty {
        photosArray = []
        for i in 0..<selectedAssets.count {

            let manager = PHImageManager.default()
            let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
            option.version = .current
            option.resizeMode = .exact
            option.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
            var thumbnail = UIImage()
            option.isSynchronous = true

            manager.requestImage(for: selectedAssets[i], targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in
                thumbnail = result!
            })

            let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnail, 0.7)
            let newImage = UIImage(data: data!)

            self.photosArray.append(newImage! as UIImage)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the correlation, if any, between the two arrays `selectedAssets` and `photosArray` and `collectionView`? Is there anything that might be changed in any off the arrays when calling `reloadData()`?

Answer (score -1):

You are reloading collection view inside the for loop .. issue might be there .. plz make it out of for loop else check in numberof rows , which array u r returning

Comment: The `for` line is correct. You mean `0...foo.count - 1` which is the same as `0..<foo.count` (please note the `<`) .